# Ruby on Rails helper caching evaluated value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a helper module in my Ruby on Rails application, and the helper (`ApplicationHelper` has a method named `is_same_user?`, which is defined like so:

```
def is_same_user?(user)
        !user.nil? && user_signed_in? && current_user.username == user.is_a?(User) ? user.username : user
end
```

When I use this helper method, it seems that the value changes sporadically. Occasionally it will return true and only true, occasionally it will function correctly, and occasionally it will return false and only false. I know it isn't the logic that is failing, because I've swapped out the logic in place of the method call and it functions perfectly fine. I know there isn't another method defined as `is_same_user?` that could be getting called instead.

It makes me wonder if it's some sort of Ruby on Rails helper caching? It's the only possible conclusion I could come to. I'm having a lot of trouble tracking down what this could possibly be, and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you written any tests or specs for this helper method?

Comment: No, I haven't, but I've tested it manually under an array of different conditions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that logic fails here a little.
I assume that You want to check if user is not nil, user is signed in and current_user.username is eqal user or user.username (based on given argument). Than there is a problem with lack of brackets.

```
> :a == true ? :a : :b
=> :b
> :a == :a ? :a : :b
=> :a
> :a == (true ? :a : :b)
=> true
```

So You have to wrap your `user.is_a?(User) ? user.username : user` with brackets:

```
!user.nil? && user_signed_in? && current_user.username == (user.is_a?(User) ? user.username : user)
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's any magic here, there's a bug and you just need to find it.

It looks like it's supposed to check if the given "user" which may be a string name or User object is the same as the current_user (Devise helper?) username?

Odds are something you're assuming should be there at all times, isn't there...

It's hard to debug as one big statement like that.  When you need to figure it out, break it up!  Here's an (untested) **absolutely hideous** way to gain some insight:

```
def is_same_user?(user)
  if user.nil?
    # possible breakpoint
    logger.debug("user is nil")
    return false
  end

  unless user_signed_in?
    # possible breakpoint
    logger.debug("no user signed in")
    return false
  end

  logger.debug("#{user.class} given: #{user}")
  if user.is_a?(User)
    # possible breakpoint
    return current_user.username == user.username
  else
    # possible breakpoint
    return current_user.username == user
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

As noted by @Michael Duda, it's operator precedence that's caused your bug, but that bug is a side-effect of putting too much code on one line.

This can be improved (and made correct) by using [guard clauses](http://blog.codinghorror.com/flattening-arrow-code/):

```
def is_same_user?(username)
  return false unless username
  return false unless user_signed_in?
  username = username.username if username.respond_to?(:username)
  current_user.username == username
end
```

Also, instead of testing whether username *is a* User, we test that it *quacks like* a User.